# how to inserts the log4j logs into cassandra

Tags: log4j, cassandra

I was trying to insert log4j logs from a Java application into Cassandra. I got the configuration for the log4j properties from http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise2.0/logging/log4j_logging.

I was not able to get the `com.datastax.logging.appender.CassandraAppender`. Can anybody let me know where to get the Cassandra appender, or is there a way we can integrate log4j and Cassandra?

Comment: Log4j is already integrated with cassandra.You just need to have all the related jar in classpath and provide the path of the logging configuration file while running your program.

Answer (score 0):

The log4j appender is part of DataStax Enterprise; it's not included in Apache Cassandra by itself.  If you're already using DataStax Enterprise, make sure that you've added `path/to/dse/resources/log4j-appender/lib/` to the classpath for your application.

Comment: Hi.. i am not using datastax enterprise since it was trial version.. i have downloaded apache cassandra 1.1.2 version.. for loggin log4j logs into cassandra i m using rviper/cassandra-log4j · GitHub project and i am getting following error.."log4j:ERROR Log4jAppender, org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'replication_factor' was not found in serialized data!" can u let me know  what i shuld do

Comment: @user1537462 If you're using a different library and having problems, I suggest opening a new question for it. It's too hard to debug issues through comments.